# Calculating percentage of loaded data from background queue using GCD

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, progress-bar, grand-central-dispatch

I amy trying to make simple progress bar in SpriteKit. To simplify the example I will use SKLabelNode and it's text property, which will indicate the progress.

Here is the code( GameScene.m ):

```
#import "GameScene.h"

@interface GameScene ()
typedef void (^CompletitionHandler)(void);
@property (nonatomic,strong)SKLabelNode* progressBar;
@end

@implementation GameScene

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    self.progressBar = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];
    self.progressBar.fontColor = [SKColor redColor];
    self.progressBar.fontSize = 24.0;
    self.progressBar.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));


    [self addChild:self.progressBar];

    [self loadSceneAssetsWithCompletionHandler:^{

        [self setupScene:view];
    }];


}

- (void)loadSceneAssetsWithCompletionHandler:(CompletitionHandler)handler {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{

        // Load the shared assets in the background.
        //This part simulates bunch of assets(textures, emitters etc) loading in background
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.01];

            float progressValue = (float)i;

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                self.progressBar.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.f", progressValue];
            });

        }

        if (!handler) {
            return;
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Call the completion handler back on the main queue.

            handler();
        });
    });
}
```

Now I am trying to find an obvious way, if there is any, to update the progress based on **percentage** of data loaded from background queue.

The problem is that I want to show percentage of loaded data from 0 to 100. But I don't know how to tell what would be 1% of bunch of textures, emitters and nodes, or I can say, I don't know how to update a progress bar after %1 is loaded. This is because I am working with different kind of objects. Is there any way to check the state of certain background queue to see how much stuff is left to be executed(loaded)?

Anybody has any idea, or suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to get an update on, for example, how much is left to load for a texture atlas then the answer is you can't.

You can however keep a "load items" counter and update that once an asset is loaded. For example, you have 13 texture atlases to load and some sound files, both of those have completion capability in their loading methods.

```
- (void)preloadWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler

playSoundFileNamed:(NSString *)soundFile
           waitForCompletion:(BOOL)wait
```

Every time an asset finishes loading, update your counter. To be honest though, I am not sure if this is really necessary as loading usually happens very quickly. Display a generic "loading" message for a few seconds is probably your best (and easiest) option.

Comment: Yeah , you are right, actually I don't need that kind  progress bar if I think better of it. Those are 2 seconds gaps between scenes...Also I thought that this will add additional complexity to code in the way you described (running some kind of completion handler for every single resource).  I'll stick to the "spinning" animation while loading resources in background.. Thanks for your answer!